# Hide/Display an element depending on a property assigned to a user role

Tags: javascript, vue.js, roles

I'm working on separating 2 main user roles, editor and guest. Editor as such is the one that has every privilege at hand for the CRUD, but guest can only view certain elements such as a List but cannot make use of some specific operations. Is there any way in vuejs to hide those elements when a user is created with, let's say, a "privilegeType" guest property?

Answer (score 1):

You could just get the user data. Have a state, stating the user roles. Using `v-if` to hide and show element based on the user roles.